# Google claims member spam--I can't find it

Tags: spam

I received this message from Google:

> Google has detected user-generated spam on your site. Typically, this
>   kind of spam is found on forum pages, guestbook pages, or in user
>   profiles. As a result, Google has applied a manual spam action to
>   4sonline.org/forums/member/.

I have seen the member spam attacks described elsewhere on the board, but that is not going on here. While the site has a few hundred members, all have been approved by me and most have never visited the site. Only three have logged in in the last two months.

Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Comment: Just got this same message today myself, and also could find no members who have any spammy links (most members on this site have no profile information filled in at all).

Comment: I got one today too. Hopefully, it was an accidentally mail blitz.

Comment: New information: In webmaster Tools, I find over 31,000 links to pages at gilbot.com "via an intermediate link" on my web site. The url cited is for a .ppt file, but the file does not exist at that location. Rather the url returns a compilation of channel entries. Perusing the source, I don't find an obviouis exploit. Not sure what to do.

Comment: No little obfuscated bits of javascript that are url injecting?

Comment: A site I work with received this as well... but I removed the forums and even redirected all forum URI's so that all access has been removed from that old section of the site. Super strange for sure.

Comment: I also received the email. Google pointed at a squeaky-clean member profile as a spam registration. I've been on a crusade against registration spam for the nine years I've operated my site. My posts about it are all over the EE boards. I personally know the owner of the targeted profile (it's a site for a geographical community), and in no way is he a spammer. I don't see how this could have happened. I have a question for the group. A couple of days before the Google email, I tried out Fruition, a site that claims to identify Google penalties. I didn't finish the registration, since they wan